# error with slap.d while installing software

Tags: ldap

I am trying to install wireshark (this issue is not specific to wireshark) on my ubuntu box and I keep getting the following error for slap.d:

```
Setting up slapd (2.4.23-6ubuntu6.1) ...
  Creating initial configuration... mkdir: cannot create directory `/etc/ldap/slapd.d': File exists
dpkg: error processing slapd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 slapd
```

Besides uninstalling or trying to update open LDAP or slap.d, is there any other action that can be taken to resolve this issue? I am trying the install as root user & I have tried moving the slap.d conf file so far but without any luck. Any thoughts on troubleshooting/resolving this issue will be quite welcome. thank in advance

Comment: See http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=596343 for an workaround

Comment: thank you for commenting Ulrich - I went through it but it did not resolve the issue.  I will retry as it could have been pilot error when I went through the instructions and was not able to resolve the issue.